# Run JAR file with os.system() in python but it doesn't work out

Tags: java, python

I have a jar file which can be use in cmd.exe using this command:

```
java -jar CWS.jar 我是中国人 out.out
```

and get some print messages in cmd.exe window and the correct output file.

But when I use this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

cmd="java -jar CWS.jar 我是中国人 out.out"
print cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

I can only see the cmd string printed, and all the original print infos from jar program does not appear. And no output file is generated.

I run the command in the same path with this python code file. CWS.jar is also in this path.

Comment: Are you in the same directory where `CWS.jar` is?

Comment: yes, the same directory

Comment: Try using `subprocess.check_output("java -jar CWS.jar 我是中国人 out.out", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` instead.

Comment: it's been a long time since I've used python2. so a wild guess: are you sure that the cmd string is indeed unicode ? can you try to create it with cmd=unicode('...')